# PHP proxy/mirroring script

Tags: php, proxy, copy, mirror

I'm looking for a way to use PHP and possibly .htaccess to create a proxy that would essentially create a "dynamic mirror" of one site.

Example: 
http://myawesome.proxy/questions/ask would fetch https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask and return it to the browser with absolute URLs properly rewritten. Then I could log in and submit a question through that proxy.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://code.google.com/p/php5rp/

It's a reverse proxy written in PHP5 using cURL.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at Apache mod_proxy. You're looking for a "reverse proxy"

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_proxy.html